# How to build stackable cards in React with react-swipe-card?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-swipeable-views

I'm looking to build a UI with stackable cards, something like:

[image]

Where there are a dynamic number of cards being the currently active card, and as the top card goes away, cards below is displayed. Very similar to Tinder's swipe-able experience.

I need to build this UI Component in my React web-app (not native). I found this library which looks very popular:

https://github.com/oliviertassinari/react-swipeable-views

However this library does not appear to support stacking view, and showing all the views at an offset as seen below.

Does anyone know if it is possible to accomplish what I'm looking for with react-swipeable-views or if there is a better library out there to accomplish UIC as seen in the image?

Comment: Did you finf something? Lookin this as well

Comment: Also looking...

Comment: Have a look at [the last example on this page from the react-spring library](https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-springs) which is similar to what you are looking. I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [react-spring](https://github.com/react-spring/react-spring) library to achieve this. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/j0y0vpz59) is an example of that behavior implemented.

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can Use :

`import { Card, CardWrapper } from "react-swipeable-cards"`

Your Card and their elements should be in CardWrapper

```
<CardWrapper >
  <Card>

  </Card>
</CardWrapper >
```